# Invalid Column Name When Open To Edit A Table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm running SQL 2008 R2. I added 3 columns to an existing table. There was not any problem. Then I opened the table to edit with right click ("edit top 200 rows"). When I write a value to the new added columns, it says invalid column name. I cleared the cache of Intellisense, but still the same error.

Comment: Did you "refresh" first (right-mouse click on table name)? Maybe the cached definition was out of date. Restarting the management studio would also help.

Comment: I did, I restarted SQL server, I restarted SQL Management tool ...

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing Tables on the ObjectExplorer, just press F5 to refresh and try again. Also you could refresh only the affected table.

Comment: Newly added columns can be seen on objectexplorer. Here is a screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/288cyyu/6